# Decode string key having integer value using JSONDecoder Swift

Tags: json, swift, codable, jsondecoder

I am working on decoding JSON data coming from API, and I am stuck in decoding image object having the key with integer value you can see in the screenshot attached, any help should be appreciated.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zh4PB.png)

Comment: And how do you want them to be represented in your struct? Is the number important? Else, use a custom `ini(from decoder:)` and manage them. And only the images? Not the keys for the roomId ?

Comment: Copy paste the code instead of screenshot

Comment: If you are responsible for the API send more suitable data. Unlike in PHP Array and Dictionary are completely different in Swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **`Codable`**, you can parse the above *JSON response* using the below model.

```
struct Room: Decodable {
    let roomId: String
    let name: String
    let images: [String:String?]
}
```

Now, parse it like,

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:Room].self, from: data)
    print(response)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```